# Can I install Tor on debian vps and then use the vps IP address: 9150 to connect my cellphone or another computer to Tor network?

Tags: debian, vps

I successfully installed Tor on my debian vps. Is there a way to connect my cell phone or another computer to Tor network using my vps? If there is a way, how should I set it up to work?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you using Tor for? What is it that is not working? What error messages did you get?

Comment: I install tor on my vps. i want use my vps like 192.3.117.xx:9150 can work my cellphone or compouters. but can't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the default `SocksPort` is 9050 for non-Tor Browser tor installations.

That said, exposing a `SocksPort` over the Internet would be a fairly bad idea (running open proxies is usually frowned upon), and accessing such a thing over the Internet would be an even worse idea, assuming you want any sort of privacy or security, as SOCKS4(a)/5 requests are sent unencrypted, so everyone in between your phone/computers and your VPS can see your destination.

If you really want to use a tor instance on a VPS that you control as your first hop, make your VPS into a Bridge, and instruct Tor Browser/Orbot/whatever to use said Bridge.